# Placing flexbox under each other when making browser window smaller

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I made a box containing some information. In this box I used flexbox to position the text and items. The thing is, on the right side I have a up and downside arrow. When making the browser smaller I want that the up and downside arrows will be place below "software engineer" only this does not happen.

I tried using:

```
.profile-box-header{
 display:flex;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

and flex-grow for this. Please check jsfiddle:

```css
*{
    font-family: verdana;
    margin: 0;
}

body{
    background: #eee;
}

.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.profile-box-wrapper{ 
    width:500px;
    height:150px;
    background:rgb(253, 253, 253);
    border-radius:4px;
    margin: 10px 10px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
 
}
.profile-box-header img{
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    margin:5px 0 0 10px;
}

.profile-box-header{
 display:flex;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.profile-name{
    margin-left:10px;
    flex-grow:1;
}

.profile-name h3{

}


.profile-right {
    margin:0;
    text-align:right;
    margin-right:5px;
    flex-grow:2;
 
}
 
.profile-box-content{
    margin:15px 0 0 10px;
}



.profile-right img{
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <title>The Net Ninja - CSS Flexbox</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <meta name="referrer" content="origin" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">

</head>

<body>

 <div class="profile-box-wrapper">
  <div class="profile-box-header">
   <img src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    alt="profile pic Nuri" />
   <div class="profile-name">
    <h2>John Doe</h2>
    <h3>j.doe@test.nl</h3>
    <p>A cool dude</p>
   </div>
   <div class="profile-right">
    <img src="http://www.iconarchive.com/download/i86026/graphicloads/100-flat-2/arrow-up.ico" /> +1
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQBfqvaL0rrs6wxMD_mzGnLyC5eg_Hd6UmzbMtZ9bJY0C1dKRc9" />-1
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="profile-box-content">
   <div class="content">
    <p>This is a lorum ipsum text</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>


 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Can someone please explain me how to use flexbox to get items under each other when making a browser smaller. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the **Flex Direction** and set it with the help of the **Media Queries**, i edited your code check this solution :

```css
*{
    font-family: verdana;
    margin: 0;
}

body{
    background: #eee;
    padding: 10px;
}

.profile-box-wrapper{ 
    width:500px;
    background:rgb(253, 253, 253);
    border-radius:4px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.profile-box-header{
    display:flex;
    align-items: center
}

.profile-box-header img{
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
}

.profile-name{
    margin-left:10px;
}

.profile-right {
    height:70px;
    margin-left:auto;
    text-align:right;
}

.profile-right img{
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
}

.profile-box-content{
    margin-top:15px;
}

@media(max-width: 520px){

    .profile-box-wrapper{ 
        width: calc(100% - 20px);
    }

    .profile-box-header{
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .profile-right {
        height: inherit;
        margin-left: inherit;
        margin-top: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .profile-box-content{
        text-align:center;
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <title>The Net Ninja - CSS Flexbox</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <meta name="referrer" content="origin" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

 <div class="profile-box-wrapper">
  <div class="profile-box-header">
   <img src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    alt="profile pic Nuri" />
   <div class="profile-name">
    <h2>John Doe</h2>
    <h3>j.doe@test.nl</h3>
    <p>Software-engineer</p>
   </div>
   <div class="profile-right">
    <img src="http://www.iconarchive.com/download/i86026/graphicloads/100-flat-2/arrow-up.ico" /> +1
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQBfqvaL0rrs6wxMD_mzGnLyC5eg_Hd6UmzbMtZ9bJY0C1dKRc9" />-1
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="profile-box-content">
   <div class="content">
    <p>This is a lorum ipsum text</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>


 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Answer of question 2 :

```css
p{
  font-size: 80%;
  opacity: .4;
}

div {
  border: 5px solid green;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  border-color: blue;
}
.container > div {
  border-color: red;
}

.line {
  position: relative;
}
.line:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<p>// In this state you can see that all children has the same height , no problem</p>
<div class="container">
  <div>child 1</div>
  <div>child 2</div>
  <div>
    <div>child of child 3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<p>// Now let's  make the height of children diffrent, this will look messy because they aren't centred at the same line</p>
<div class="container line">
  <div style="height:90px;">child 1</div>
  <div  style="height:120px;">child 2</div>
  <div  style="height:60px;">
    <div>child of child 3</div>
  </div>
</div>


<br>
<p>// Now let's  centre the children at the same line this will be perfect add to our parent container <b>align-items: center;</b></p>
<div class="container line" style="align-items: center;">
  <div style="height:90px;">child 1</div>
  <div  style="height:120px;">child 2</div>
  <div  style="height:60px;">
    <div>child of child 3</div>
  </div>
</div>


<br>
<p>// Put the last child to the right using <b>margin-left: auto;</b></p>
<div class="container line" style="align-items: center;">
  <div style="height:90px;">child 1</div>
  <div  style="height:120px;">child 2</div>
  <div  style="height:60px;margin-left: auto;">
    <div>child of child 3</div>
  </div>
</div>



<br>
<p>// Now our <b>child 3</b> should be at the top of his parent so , it should take the max height of his parent but our parent has default height so it will take the max height of his children , in this state  <b>child 2</b> has the max height, so we will set the height of <b>child 3</b> at same height or heigher then <b>child 2</b> wich is  in this state <b> child 2 height > 120px</b> </p>
<div class="container line" style="align-items: center;">
  <div style="height:90px;">child 1</div>
  <div  style="height:120px;">child 2</div>
  <div  style="height:120px; margin-left: auto;">
    <div>child of child 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool solution, do you know why height:70px; in the profile-right class makes the arrows go in the upper left corner instead of centering it? because if i remove the height then it will go near the center.

Comment: @YdB  in the `.profile-box-header` class  i add `align-items: center` this will make its children be centred , so if you will remove the `70px` it will be centred so i set it the height  as much as the height of the image this will force him to be to the top , and  about  `margin-left: auto` this will make the child go to right  of his parent , i hope this was  clear ^^ !!

Comment: Thanks Kr for the explanation and time! I still not understand why it goes top why setting the heigth the same as the left image

Comment: @YdB i add another **snippet code*  answering your question , run the code i give an example , i hope this time it will be clear  !! if this resolve your problem don't forget to accept the solution  ^^ !!

Answer (score 1):

If you want only to wrap the icons without media queries you can try this

```css
*{
    font-family: verdana;
    margin: 0;
}

body{
    background: #eee;
}

.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.flex-wrapper{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  flex-grow: 1 ;
  
}

.profile-box-wrapper{ 
    max-width:500px;
    height:150px;
    background:rgb(253, 253, 253);
    border-radius:4px;
    margin: 10px 10px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
 
}
.profile-box-header img{
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    margin:5px 0 0 10px;
}

.profile-box-header{
 display:flex;

}

.profile-name{
    margin-left:10px;
    flex-grow:1;
}

.profile-name h3{

}


.profile-right {
    margin:0;
    text-align:right;
    margin-right:5px;
    
 
}
 
.profile-box-content{
    margin:15px 0 0 10px;
}



.profile-right img{
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <title>The Net Ninja - CSS Flexbox</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <meta name="referrer" content="origin" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">

</head>

<body>

 <div class="profile-box-wrapper">
  <div class="profile-box-header">
   <img src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    alt="profile pic Nuri" />
       <div class="flex-wrapper">
   <div class="profile-name">
    <h2>John Doe</h2>
    <h3>j.doe@test.nl</h3>
    <p>Software-engineer</p>
   </div>
   <div class="profile-right">
    <img src="http://www.iconarchive.com/download/i86026/graphicloads/100-flat-2/arrow-up.ico" /> +1
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQBfqvaL0rrs6wxMD_mzGnLyC5eg_Hd6UmzbMtZ9bJY0C1dKRc9" />-1
   </div>
  </div>
    </div>
  <div class="profile-box-content">
   <div class="content">
    <p>This is a lorum ipsum text</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>


 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

changed `width` to `max-width` in `.profile-box-wrapper` so the `profile-box-wrapper` can become smaller than `500px`.
added `.flex-wrapper` around `profile-name` and `profile-right` so the icons will be under `profile-name` when they wrap.
`.flex-wrapper` is a flexbox, added `flex-wrap:wrap;` so the icons can wrap.
`flex-grow: 1;` is used so `.flex-wrapper` takes the remaining width.
check out this guide for css flex [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Can you please explain

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that scales.

```css
        body {
            margin: 0;
            background: #eee;
            font-family: verdana;
        }

        img {
            max-width: 100%;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .users {
            position: relative;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            min-height: 1px;
            vertical-align: top;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 960px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
        }

        .users-list-wrapper {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            margin: 0;
            position: relative;
            float: none;
        }

        .users-list-card {
            background: #fff;
            width: calc(33.3% - 60px);
            text-align: left;
            position: relative;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 20px;
        }

        @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 960px) {
            .users-list-card {
                width: calc(50% - 60px);
            }
        }

        @media (max-width: 767px) {
            .users-list-card {
                width: 100%;
                display: block;
            }
        }

        .users-list-card-header {
            display: flex;
        }

        .users-list-card-header h2 {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .users-list-card-header img {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            margin-right: 20px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>The Net Ninja - CSS Flexbox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta name="referrer" content="origin" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="user-list">
        <div class="users-list-wrapper">
            <div class="users-list-card">
                <div class="users-list-card-header">
                    <img src="data:image/png;base64,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"
                        alt="profile pic Nuri" />
                    <div>
                        <h2>John Doe</h2>
                        <h3>j.doe@test.nl</h3>
                        <p>Software-engineer</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="users-list-card">
                <div class="users-list-card-header">
                    <img src="data:image/png;base64,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"
                        alt="profile pic Nuri" />
                    <div>
                        <h2>John Doe</h2>
                        <h3>j.doe@test.nl</h3>
                        <p>Software-engineer</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="users-list-card">
                <div class="users-list-card-header">
                    <img src="data:image/png;base64,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"
                        alt="profile pic Nuri" />
                    <div>
                        <h2>John Doe</h2>
                        <h3>j.doe@test.nl</h3>
                        <p>Software-engineer</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>



    </div>
</body>

</html>
```